# why these two programs result in diffrent results?

Tags: python, parameters

I have changed the value of 'a' before calling the function get_size() in both the programs

1st:

```
a=''
def get_size(b):
    size=len(b)
    return size

def main():
    a='qwerr'
    print 'the size of a is:',get_size(a)
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

console:`the size of a is: 5`

---

2nd:

```
a=''

def get_size():
    size=len(a)
    return size

def main():
    a='qwerr'
    print 'the size of a is:',get_size()
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

console:`the size of a is: 0`

Answer (score 1):

It's a scope problem.  The first program creates `a` in the local scope of `main()`, then passes that to `get_size()`, while the second program references the global `a` from within `get_size()`.  If you want the second one to work as you expect, you need to make `a` global within `main()` scope.

```
main()
    global a
    a = 'qwerr'
    print 'the size of a is:',get_size()
```

As pointed out in the comments, a `main()`-scoped `a` is created in both versions, but since `get_size()` in version 1 references the global `a`, setting the local `a` in `main()` has no impact on what `get_size()` operates on.

Really though, you should try not to use globals, in part to avoid exactly the ambiguity you are experiencing here.

Comment: In *both* programs, `main` creates a local `a`.

Comment: @delnan Yes, but since `get_size()` uses the global `a` in the first version, that fact is irrelevant.  I'll try to update the wording of my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

In the first program, you are setting a at global scope, then resetting it to another string in def main scope.

Answer (score 0):

In the second program, get_size method will check for 'a' value in its local scope but as it is not there in it's local scope and then it will verify in it's global scope